# Воспроизведение захваченных данных с помощью OpenAL

Tags: c++

Я изучаю OpenAL и обнаружил код, который захватывает данные и воспроизводит их. Я имею в виду эхо. Я действительно хочу сделать приложение для голосового чата, но я не могу воспроизвести полученные данные. Вот код, в котором я сделал некоторые небольшие изменения. Ребята, я знаю, что это большой и скучный код для чтения, но мне действительно нужна ваша помощь, идеи. Пожалуйста, дайте 5 минут золотого времени для моего кода :).

```
 #include <al.h>    // OpenAL header files
#include <alc.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <vector>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ALCdevice *dev[2];
    ALCcontext *ctx;
    ALuint source, buffers[3];
    char data[5000];
    ALuint buf;
    ALint val;

    float ttotal;
    unsigned int ccount;
    long int c1ount;
    c1ount = 0;

    dev[0] = alcOpenDevice(NULL);
    ctx = alcCreateContext(dev[0], NULL);
    alcMakeContextCurrent(ctx);

    alGenSources(1, &source);
    alGenBuffers(3, buffers);

    /* Setup some initial silent data to play out of the source */
    alBufferData(buffers[0], AL_FORMAT_MONO16, data, sizeof(data), 22050);
    alBufferData(buffers[1], AL_FORMAT_MONO16, data, sizeof(data), 22050);
    alBufferData(buffers[2], AL_FORMAT_MONO16, data, sizeof(data), 22050);

    alSourceQueueBuffers(source, 3, buffers);

    std::vector<ALuint> my_vector;

    /* If you don't need 3D spatialization, this should help processing time */
    alDistanceModel(AL_NONE);

    dev[1] = alcCaptureOpenDevice(NULL, 22050, AL_FORMAT_MONO16, sizeof(data) / 2); //22050 mean 22.050 samples per     second. or 44100 for 44.1 per second.

    /* Start playback and capture, and enter the audio loop */

    alSourcePlay(source);
    alcCaptureStart(dev[1]);    //starts ring buffer

    while (1)
    {
        alGetSourcei(source, AL_BUFFERS_PROCESSED, &val);
        if (val <= 0) {
            continue;
        }

        /* Check how much audio data has been captured (note that 'val' is the
        * number of frames, not bytes) */
        alcGetIntegerv(dev[1], ALC_CAPTURE_SAMPLES, 1, &val);

        /* Read the captured audio */
        alcCaptureSamples(dev[1], data, val);

        //***** Process/filter captured data here *****//

        c1ount = c1ount + 1;
        if (c1ount >= 55) {
            break;
        }

        //***** end Process/filter captured data here *****//

        /* Pop the oldest finished buffer, fill it with the new capture data,
        then re-queue it to play on the source */

        alSourceUnqueueBuffers(source, 1, &buf);
        alBufferData(buf, AL_FORMAT_MONO16, data, val * 2 /* bytes here, not
                                                              frames */, 22050);


        alSourceQueueBuffers(source, 1, &buf);

        my_vector.push_back(buf); // here i want to keep this data so that i 
                                  //could use it later

        /* Make sure the source is still playing */
        alGetSourcei(source, AL_SOURCE_STATE, &val);

        if (val != AL_PLAYING){
            alSourcePlay(source);
        }

    }

    cout << "DONE\n";

    ALuint new_source;

    alGenSources(1, &new_source); ------------------->
```

если вы скомпилируете этот код, все в порядке, но теперь я хочу создать новый источник и захочу повторно воспроизвести полученные данные из my_vector и теперь ... в моем коде есть много проблем, которые НЕ стоит показывать, и позже, если мне удастся повторно воспроизвести данные ЗДЕСЬ с вашей помощью :) Я хочу отправить данные через Интернет с помощью ostream и получить его с помощью istream на другом ноутбуке и воспроизвести эти данные, то есть мою идею голосового чата :) Пожалуйста, помогите мне сыграть эти данные. Большое спасибо за вашу помощь заранее!